# How to get substrings using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Suppose, I have a string `name = 'baceb'` 
I want to store its substrings into a list. 
For `baceb` the substrings will be like - "b, ba, bac, bace, a, ac, ace, aceb, c, ce, ceb, e, eb, baceb" 
How can I get this substrings easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a list of all the substrings with a simple nested list comprehension:

```
s = 'baceb'
subs = [s[i:j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i,len(s))]
```

This will however give you a repeated value, `b`, which occurs as both the first and last substring:

```
['b', 'ba', 'bac', 'bace', 'baceb', 'a', 'ac', 'ace', 'aceb', 'c', 'ce', 'ceb', 'e', 'eb', 'b']
```

If you don't want any duplicates, and you don't care about ordering, use a set comprehension instead and then convert to a list:

```
subs = list({ s[i:j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i,len(s)) })
```

Output:

```
['e', 'ba', 'a', 'aceb', 'c', 'ceb', 'eb', 'bac', 'baceb', 'bace', 'ce', 'ac', 'b', 'ace']
```

If you do care about ordering, there are many good solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order) that describe how to remove duplicates from a list while preserving ordering.

Comment: Might be slightly neater to use a set comprehension (`{... for i in ...}`) rather than list comprehension and then convert to set.

Comment: @Oli good point, I had written the `set` code as a follow-on to the `list` code, but it's more optimal to do it that way; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import itertools

s = 'baceb'
lst = [[s[i:j+1] for j in range(i,len(s))] for i in range(len(s))]
ss = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))
print(ss)
```

Output

```
{'e', 'ba', 'a', 'aceb', 'b', 'ace', 'bac', 'bace', 'ce', 'c', 'baceb', 'ceb', 'eb', 'ac'}
```